# Events not being handled from a user control and main form

Tags: wpf, vb.net, events, mvvm, event-handling

I am attempting to handle an event in the application main form where said event is being raised from a user control populated on the main form.  I've defined an Interface for the event which is being implemented in both the Main Form and the User Control.  I'm using MvvmLight from GalaSoft for the MVVM support.

The main form code behind indicates that the event is attached, but when I do the check in the user control, it indicates that there is no handler attached to the event, so obviously, it won't ever get to the handler.

Any help would be appreciated.

The interface I've defined is pretty basic:

```
Public Interface IEventFiring
   Event EventFiring(sender As Object)
End Interface
```

My Main Form Xaml looks like this:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:EventFiringFromContolToMainForm"
        xmlns:efc="clr-namespace:EventFiringControl;assembly=EventFiringControl"
    Title="MainWindow">
   <Window.DataContext>
      <local:MainWindowViewModel/>
   </Window.DataContext>
    <StackPanel>
      <TextBox Text="{Binding StatusText, Mode=OneWay}"
               Height="25"
                 Margin="5"/>
       <Separator Margin="5"/>
       <efc:UserControl1/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

The Code Behind is:

```
Imports EventFiringControl

Class MainWindow
   Implements IEventFiring

   Public Sub New()

      ' This call is required by the designer.
      InitializeComponent()

      ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
      AddHandler EventFiring, AddressOf EventFiringSub

      If EventFiringEvent Is Nothing Then
         CType(DataContext, MainWindowViewModel).StatusText = "Event did NOT Attach!!"
      Else
         CType(DataContext, MainWindowViewModel).StatusText = "Event Attached"
      End If

   End Sub

   Public Event EventFiring(sender As Object) Implements IEventFiring.EventFiring

   Private Sub EventFiringSub()
      CType(DataContext, MainWindowViewModel).StatusText = "Event Fired"
   End Sub
End Class
```

The view model for the Main Form is:

```
Imports GalaSoft.MvvmLight

Public Class MainWindowViewModel
   Inherits ViewModelBase

   Private _statusText As String

   Public Property StatusText As String
      Get
         Return _statusText
      End Get
      Set(value As String)
         _statusText = value
         RaisePropertyChanged(Function() StatusText)
      End Set
   End Property

End Class
```

Now for the User Control.

Xaml file is:

```
<UserControl x:Class="UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:EventFiringControl"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
   <UserControl.DataContext>
      <local:EventFiringViewModel/>
   </UserControl.DataContext>
    <Grid>
            <Button Content="Cancel" Command="{Binding CancelCommand}" Height="50"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The code behind is:

```
Public Class UserControl1 
   Public Sub New()

      ' This call is required by the designer.
      InitializeComponent()

      ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

   End Sub
End Class
```

Finally, the View Model for the User Control is:

```
Imports GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command
Imports GalaSoft.MvvmLight

Public Class EventFiringViewModel
   Inherits ViewModelBase
   Implements IEventFiring

   Public ReadOnly Property CancelCommand As RelayCommand
      Get
         Return New RelayCommand(Sub() CancelSub())
      End Get
   End Property

   Private Sub CancelSub()
      If EventFiringEvent IsNot Nothing Then
         RaiseEvent EventFiring(Me)
      End If
   End Sub


   Public Event EventFiring(sender As Object) Implements IEventFiring.EventFiring
End Class
```

Comment: Looks like you have different instances of your EventFiringViewModel. In UserControl it should be same as in Window. You do not need to create it explicitly in your UserControl xaml, it will be transferred from Window DataContext

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean.  Can you give an idea as to how to adjust my code to make it work?

Comment: Remove this:
    <UserControl.DataContext>
      <local:EventFiringViewModel/>
   </UserControl.DataContext>

Comment: Ok.  Where do you suggest setting the DataContext?

Comment: You set it here:
  <Window.DataContext>
      <local:MainWindowViewModel/>
   </Window.DataContext>

Comment: I commented out the item from my xaml file.  Now the datacontext is NOT set.  If I put a breakpoint in my viewmodel constructor, it never fires.  When I leave the code in, my viewmodel constructor is fired only once, but the event handling still does not work.  An additional benefit for using the xaml approach to specifying the datacontext is that whenever I do a binding, the xaml understands the properties from the designated view model.  I have found that using this approach consistently works for setting the datacontext rather than putting it in the code behind.  Other suggestions?

Comment: Maybe I need to make myself a little clearer.  I want to be able to fire the event from my control, which has it's own data context and "Handle" the event in the Main window's code behind or data context.  I had already designated the datacontext for the main window using the lines you indicated.  I think you should see that in my original post.

Comment: In this case you can create childVM in your main window VM and use it as DataContext for your user control.